# WPF DataGrid updates all rows based on changes

Tags: wpf, datagrid, f#

For a GUI app I'm working on, I need to have a grid for editing schedules. Each schedule is an array of an "hours" object, defined as:

```
type Hour = { // 24-hour units for every day
    mutable Sunday    : bool
    mutable Monday    : bool
    mutable Tuesday   : bool
    mutable Wednesday : bool
    mutable Thursday  : bool
    mutable Friday    : bool
    mutable Saturday  : bool
}
```

These objects are layed out in the following data grid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Sunday" Binding="{Binding Sunday}"  Width="*" />
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Monday" Binding="{Binding Monday}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Tuesday" Binding="{Binding Tuesday}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Wednesday" Binding="{Binding Wednesday}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Thursday" Binding="{Binding Thursday}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Friday" Binding="{Binding Friday}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Saturday" Binding="{Binding Saturday}" Width="*" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Any time a row is changed in the data grid, this results in the entire column receiving the same change (once the data grid is refreshed). For example, if I unset 5:00 on Wednesday, the entire Wednesday column becomes unset. If I set 8:00 on Monday, all of Monday becomes set once the data grid is refreshed.

The relevant parts of the F# code for this:

```
type SchedulePage (schedule : Hour[]) as self =
  inherit SchedulePageBase () // XAML<"SchedulePage.xaml">
  do self.DataContext <- self

  let mutable schedule = schedule
  member self.Rows with get () = schedule and set value = schedule <- value
```

My theory is that the `set` method for `self.Rows` isn't being called. I tried to test this by adding a MessageBox dialog to pop-up every time the row `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to each Binding, but this did not change the results. I'm not sure what this means, because the results definitely do change, however this method doesn't seem to be getting called. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you construct your instance of `SchedulePage`?

Comment: Sure, I have the following code:
    let blankSchedule = Array.create 24 {
      Sunday    = false
      Monday    = false
      Tuesday   = false
      Wednesday = false
      Thursday  = false
      Friday    = false
      Saturday  = false
    }

I simply have `SchedulePage blankSchedule` to construct it and I reuse the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an array of 24 references to the same instance of `Hour`. Not 24 different instances of `Hour`, but only one instance, with 24 references to it. It is, therefore, not surprising that, when the user checks one checkbox, all 24 rows get it checked, because they are all bound to the same object.

In order to create 24 separate instances of `Hour`, use `Array.init`:

```
let blankSchedule = Array.init 24 (fun _ ->  
    { Sunday = false; Monday = false; Tuesday = false 
      Wednesday = false; Thursday = false; Friday = false; Saturday = false })
```

Also (as an aside), with your current setup, you don't really need the `SchedulePage.Rows` property to be writeable. Nobody ever writes to it. Just make it a `member val`:

```
type SchedulePage (schedule : Hour[]) as self =
   inherit SchedulePageBase ()
   do self.DataContext <- self
   member val Rows = schedule
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I never really use mutability in F#, I guess I never considered the semantics of it.